# my jenkins have to build a .net service, but has a dependency library file in other repository, so how to use library when jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, buildconfiguration

I use gitlab and jenkins.

Here is my structure:

**branch: master**

Inside the app_folder I have the following files:

- app_folder

  - solution_folder
  - core_library
  - other services
  - 3rd party dll
- services_folder

  - service1_folder
  - service2_folder
  - service3_folder
  - service_sln

All three services use `same services_sln` file.

Now these services use the core libraries in the other directory which was mentioned above.

How do I configure the jenkins build?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't build your project. In order for jenkins to build successfully, your project should have the right configuration done in the solution file. With your problem statement, the project will not even build locally.

So get your basics right first